# Erro na criação de um projeto maven

Tags: java, spring, maven

Assim que crio um projeto Maven com o packaging "war" , ela dá o seguinte erro :

```
 Description Resource Path Location Type web.xml is missing and <failOnMissingWebXml> is set to true pom.xml
```

Estou usando a Ide do Spring STE

**Segue abaixo meu pom.xml**

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>primefaces</groupId>
   <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
   <name>test prime</name>
   <description>testar primefaces responsive layout</description>
 </project>
```

Comment: Está usando Eclipse né?

Answer (score 1):

No erro diz que está faltando o `web.xml`.
Crie a Pasta `WEB-INF` dentro de `webapp` e em seguida crie o arquivo `web.xml`.